# Data Transformation in Oracle Apex 4.2

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-apex

In *Oracle Apex 4.2* I am trying to create some transformational rules when data loading and I can't find any examples. The transformation I am trying to accomplish is sometime the users forget to remove the `lbs` off the weight column in their text file so I'd like to be able to remove the `lbs` from, say, `410 lbs` to give `410` as a numeric.

I have tried things like

```
{ 
to_number(translate(:P5_WEIGHT,'0ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz*~!#$%^()_-+=&#}]{{/?.,><','0'))
}
```

where the page is `P5` I've also tried `:P<N>WEIGHT` and `:P<N>_Weight`, both of which I have seen. Any examples of *pl/sql* or *sql* transformations are welcome.

Thanks

Fiacre the newbie.

Comment: This is for a normal form page? You want the item to be a number field?

Comment: Are you using the CSV Data Load feature in Apex, or is it just an ordinary text item on a form?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by `<N>` in `:P<N>WEIGHT`? Are you unsure what the item identifier is?

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use something like:

```
TO_NUMBER(TRIM(' lbs' FROM :P5_WEIGHT))
```